# PowerShell multiple IF statements and ForEach loops

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm struggling to understand why the below script is failing once it gets to the 2nd ForEach/IF statement.

[Multiple ForEach/IF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMwFl.png)

Could anyone please explain why this doesn't work? And how I would go about having multiple independent If statements with an action within the same script?

```
#Get the SharePoint list contents
$listItems= (Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Fields "Title","InquestTwoDate", "InquestThreeDate" -PageSize 1000) 

#Iterate through each item in the List and set date to null
ForEach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
If($listItem[“InquestTwoDate”] -eq "$date")
    {    
        Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $listItem -Values @{“InquestTwoDate”=$null}
        #Write-Host $listItem[“InquestTwoDate”]
    }
    }
#Iterate through each item in the List and set date to null
ForEach ($listItem in $listItems)
{
If($listItem[“InquestThreeDate”] -eq "$date")
    {    
        Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $listItem -Values @{“InquestThreeDate”=$null}
        #Write-Host $listItem[“InquestThreeDate”]
    }
    }
```

```
Error:
At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:23 char:14
If($listItem[â€œInquestTwoDateâ€
~
Array index expression is missing or not valid.
At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:23 char:14
If($listItem[â€œInquestTwoDateâ€
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Unexpected token 'â€œInquestTwoDateâ€At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:23 char:14
If($listItem[â€œInquestTwoDateâ€
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'If' statement.
At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:22 char:1
{
~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:23 char:47
If($listItem[â€œInquestTwoDateâ€
~Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:25 char:76
... t-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $listItem -Values @{â€œInques ...
~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:32 char:14
If($listItem[â€œInquestThreeDateâ€
~
Array index expression is missing or not valid.At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:32 char:14If($listItem[â€œInquestThreeDateâ€
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Unexpected token 'â€œInquestThreeDateâ€At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:32 char:14If($listItem[â€œInquestThreeDateâ€
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'If' statement.
At C:\Users\%user%\Documents\PowerShell\Upload SharePoint items from CSV\deletedatefields2.ps1:31 char:1
{
~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
Not all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.
CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArrayIndexExpression
```

Comment: Please post the code in plain text, properly formatted. Also include `$listitems`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - Added, thanks.

Comment: If you say your script is "failing", then you should include the error message in your question.

Comment: @marsze Added, thanks.

Comment: @alexthannah You should use regular double quotes instead: `["InquestTwoDate"]`

Comment: @marsze - thanks that was the issue in the end. I think Word must of replaced the double quotes when I did a Find & Replace - that's the only way I can repeat the characters “ ”

Answer (score 0):

From [marsze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060966)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69757507/powershell-multiple-if-statements-and-foreach-loops/70817928#comment123305768_69757507)

> You should use regular double quotes instead: `["InquestTwoDate"]`